# I can understand being deceived into thinking it's a joke

Tags: sentence, passive-voice

I am having a problem in understanding this sentence:

**I can understand being deceived into thinking it's a joke.**

Does it mean that the speaker is being deceived into thinking like that or he (the speaker) thinks that someone is being deceived into thinking like that. I mean does it mean:

◆ **I can understand I am being deceived into thinking it's a joke.**

Or

◆ **I can understand someone is being deceived into thinking it's a joke.**

Actually, I have read that the continuous(present,past,future) passive voice structure is like this: *sub+helping verb+being+ past participle+preposition+object*, but here, the (sub and helping verb) part is missing and I want to know the reason. Please explain it to me.

## TIA

Comment: It _could_ mean the introspective 'I can understand my being deceived into thinking it's a joke' [',can't you?'], obviously when one has realised / been informed that it is not a joke. But  'I can understand Tom, Dick and Harry [say] being deceived into thinking it's a joke' is far more likely: 'People are often so gullible. I can understand being deceived into thinking it's a joke. Especially with such a manipulative conman.'

Comment: Thanks Edwin 

Answer (score -1):

**I** The second choice is the proper one, bar a small difference.

- I can understand there is the possibility of being deceived into thinking it's a joke.

**II** It's just a gerund; it functions as a noun (head of a noun phrase, ([ref.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase))) the use is as in this example.

- I understand wanting to work on large projects with lots of smart people from around the world. I understand wanting to get recognition for that work.